# how to import data from excel to mysql database quickly?

Tags: mysql, excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Importing excel data in mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729835/importing-excel-data-in-mysql-database)

Dear friends,

I have about 5000 rows of excel data with 15 fields that must go in mysql database, what is a quick solution for this ?