# create sql table in mysql from spreadsheet (like oracle application builder)

Tags: mysql

I want to create a table from xml spreadsheet or csv file in MySQL.

How can I do it ?

Comment: This appears to be very similiar to [3621798](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621798) or [8031193](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031193)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use [load data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) on your CSV.