# Uploading delimited excel data into a MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, database, excel

I've got a huge excel file (~6GB) that I've had to split up into multiple files. Now I need to be able to take each file and upload it into a MySQL database so I can search through it. The format each row is displayed in is as follows:

```
6003393,"Walgreens","670 N Lake Ave","Pasadena","CA","91101-1220","Los Angeles","6265858926","","","","","","","20 to 49","2.5 to 5 million","591205","Pharmacies & Drug Stores"
```

How would I go about doing this efficiently with this much data?

Thank you.

Comment: This appears to be very similiar to [3621798](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621798) or [8031193](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031193)

Answer (score 2):

Look into the [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) syntax. As long as your CSV is well-formed, it should be able to load up all of it... eventually.